# How to add language switcher to top links?

Tags: language, toplinks

I'm looking for a way to add the language switcher to my top links menu. My store has 2 languages and I've modified the languages.phtml file to show the alternate language.

*Example:* if you are on the English site, then the language switcher will show French as a clickable option to bring you to that store view.

I know that in order to add options to the top links menu, you need to modify the customer.xml file. I know how to add alternate links as I've read plenty of "how to's" however none cover how to *add the language bar*.

Here is the modifications to
**languages.phtml**

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">    
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
    <?php if($_lang->getId() != $this->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>"<?php echo $_selected; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The end result should be:

```
Login | My Cart | Compare | Wish List | LANGUAGE
```

**How can I add the language bar to the top links menu items?**

**UPDATE**

I've tried adding the following to the customer.xml file under :

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

Nothing appears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create your extension with it's own layout file and block that adds links to the top menu.
Let's call that `Easylife_Locale`. You will need the following files:

`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Locale.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Locale>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Locale>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Locale/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Locale>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Locale>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <easylife_locale>
                <class>Easylife_Locale_Block</class>
            </easylife_locale>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <easylife_locale>
                    <file>easylife_locale.xml</file>
                </easylife_locale>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/easylife_locale.xml` - the frontend layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="easylife_locale/stores" name="stores_links">
                <action method="addStoreLinks"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Locale/Block/Stores.php` - the block that adds the links to the top.

```
<?php

class Easylife_Locale_Block_Stores extends Mage_Page_Block_Switch {
    public function addStoreLinks() {
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock) {
            $position = 200; //start position
            foreach ($this->getStores() as $store) {
                $params = null;
                if ($store->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) {
                    $params = 'class="current-store"';
                    //if you want to skip the current store view just uncomment the next line
                    //continue;
                }
                //Print the language code (en, fr)
                $text = substr(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode(), 0, 2);
                //if your want to display the store name comment the line above and uncomment the one below
                //$text = $store->getName();
                $title = $store->getName();

                $parentBlock->addLink($text, $store->getCurrentUrl(), $title, false, array(), $position, null, $params);
                $position += 10;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and try it out.

Comment: Really happy to meet you in a couple weeks in Vegas, man!

Comment: @benmarks. I'm looking forward to meeting a lot of people in Vegas. See you there.

Comment: Got this to work, but how can I only display the alternate language? Currently it shows both available languages. If on English view I'd want to show French as a click-able option and on French view English as a click-able option. Really appreciate it Marius!

Comment: @sr_magento. See my comment in the code `if you want to skip the current store view just uncomment the next line`. Below that comment there is a line that says `continue;`. Uncomment that line and then the current store view will be skipped when showing the links. This way when viewing the `En` store view you will see only the `Fr` link and the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look in these 2 templates: *base/default/template/page/switch/flags.phtml* and *base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml* you will see that the magic is all about the loop using **$this->getStores()**.

Both phtmls are blocks from **Mage_Page_Block_Switch** and the method getStore() is implemented there... You can just create your from this class

```
<block type="page/switch" template="your_phtml" />
```

and use it where you need.

Comment: I've tried to implement your suggestion in the customer.xml in the layout and it's just not working. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>store_language</name></action> <!--not name, is in fact alias -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="insert"><blockName>store_language</blockName></action> <!-- block name -->
        </reference>
    </reference>
</default>

/* in page/template/links.phtml */
echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language');
```

If it's good than try to set a different template than page/template/links.phtml for top.links so you won't have the call to the child block in all blocks that use Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links, like in footer links which is cached.