# How to add dynamic link to top-links?

Tags: magento-1.8, toplinks

For my custom module i need to add one top-menu to homepage. Path may change according to the value given in configuration section.
How can i add dynamic link to the top-menu item.Please help

Comment: you want to add something to the top menu, the one that contains the categories, or the top links, the one with "My account"?

Comment: Near "My Account" I wish to add one menu named "News".The path of this menu may change with path given in the adminpanel configuration settings section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can add dynamic links to the top menu: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18947/146.
In the example above the languages are added to the top links, but you can modify your block to include any language.
All you need to change is:  `Easylife_Locale_Block_Stores::addStoreLinks` and make it look like this:

```
public function addStoreLinks() {
    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    if ($parentBlock) {
        $position = 200; //start position
        $newsLinkPath = Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/value_here');
        $newsLink = Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>$newsLinkPath));
        $title = $this->__('News');
        $text = $title;
        $parentBlock->addLink($text, $newsLink, $title, false, array(), $position);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Feel free to rename your method as you want just make sure you change its name in the layout file also.